# ¿Qué ocurre con las "k" en Stackoverflow?

Tags: soporte, reputación

Las `k` son una abreviatura de *kilo* (*miles*).

Así, `1k = 1000`; `10.2k = 10,200`...

Ignoro el tipo de cálculo que hace SO. Lo cierto es que actualmente yo tengo 10,184 puntos, como se muestra en la parte superior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la parte inferior SO muestra: **`10.2k`**, que para mí es equivalente a 10,200:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo interpreta SO los `k`?

Comment: como comentario.. en realidad k vale 1024.. lo de mil, es una abreviatura de la abreviatura...

Comment: Al poner el cursor en la reputación sale el número exacto en un tooltip.

Comment: @gbianchi: En realidad k vale mil, es kB la que vale 1024 :)

Comment: @Rubén buen punto.. pero k es la simplificacion de kB.. y asi podemos estar todo el dia.. pero te lo tomo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi: Lo sé, lo sé... (aún seguimos en elecciones, y pues ...) ¡Feliz lunes!

Comment: Interesante detalle el del tooltip @ArtEze.

Comment: Exacto @Rubén 1024=1Kb. Lo de K para los miles se hizo famoso al final del siglo pasado... se hablaba mucho de 2K: películas, virus informáticos, etc. Veremos lo que pasa en el año 3K, aunque no desde aquí.

Comment: k es la abreviatura de kilo, que viene del griego χίλιοι, y significa un millar, esto es así desde hace siglos. Igual que m es abreviatura de mili y significa una milésima. k no es abreviatura de kB. Y kB es abreviatura de kilobyte que originalmente significaba 1024 bytes pero a finales del siglo pasado, principalmente como consecuencia del etiquetado que hacían los fabricantes de DVD, empezó a tener dos significados en conflicto : 1024 bytes (el kilobyte binario) o 1000 bytes (el kilobyte decimal, que se ajusta más a la nomenclatura científica habitual).

Comment: `m` ¿no es abreviatura de Metro @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos?

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, m también es abreviatura de metro. Que sea una u otra cosa se sabe por el contexto. Así **mm** significa milímetro, **km** significa kilómetro y **ms** significa milisegundo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Esto es solo una cuestión de redondeo. Como se ve en la mayoría de los usuarios, acá o en otros sitios de la red, se tomo k como 1000, pero a la hora de mostrar resultados, solo los esta redondeando. Veamos algunos ejemplos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dice, 2.2k cuando mi reputacion es 2225 (o sea redondeo para abajo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dios Jon, le pasa lo mismo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Jorgesys, con 38488, es un ejemplo de redondear para arriba...

O sea que.. se redondea el número.. y k vale 1000..

Comment: Es correcto, pero no lo llamaría "problema", ya que es el comportamiento deseado

Comment: punto para mariano.. ya lo corrijo.. no fue una buena elección de palabras...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Imaginé que se trataba de un redondeo, pero no estaba seguro.